# Logic over an interval

Tags: abstract-algebra, logic

What is the name of the logic where a predicate has a value over the interval domain $$P \in [0,1]$$ and conjunction is defined as multiplication $$P \land Q = P \cdot Q$$, negation as $$\neg P = 1-P$$ and de morgans law to derive disjunction. $$P \lor Q = \neg (\neg P \land \neg Q) = 1-((1-P) \cdot (1-Q))$$ where paradoxes in classical logic can be resolved with predicates assigned values besides just 0 or 1?

Comment: Given the more-or-less questionable assumptions of such logics, I doubt they will have widely adopted naming conventions. That said, there are several papers which refer to them as "continuous logics". Here's an example: https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/~henson/cfo/UCLA09text.pdf

Comment: Thanks! This is just what i was looking for.

Comment: I don't think there's a general consensus on the name of this type of logic, but personally I've called it "Continuum Logic" in the past.

Comment: There's also [fuzzy logic](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuzzy_logic).